# Overriding abstract members of abstract classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, abstract-class, abstract-data-type

I have a base abstract class `BasePerson`. I have another abstract class `BaseStudent` and this inherits from `BasePerson`. Here is the example.

```
public abstract class BasePerson
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public abstract object this[string propertyName]{get;set;}
}

public abstract class BaseStudent : BasePerson
{
    public string Test{get;set;}
    //this class inherits from BasePerson and it forces to override the indexer.
    //I can do this:
    public override object this[string propertyName]
    {
        get{return null;} 
        set
        {
            //do stuff;
        }
    }
}

public class Student : StudentBase
{
    //other properties
}
```

Now I am not  able to force `Student` class to override the indexer. What should I do to force Student to override the indexer? I can't remove the indexer from `BasePerson` class.

Help appreciated!

Comment: I'd say there's something wrong with your class hierarchy if you want to remove the indexer from `BaseStudent` when `BaseStudent` inherits from `BasePerson`. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: If you want to _force_ it, don't implement it on `BaseStudent`. Since `BaseStudent` is `abstract`, it does not _need_ to implement all the `abstract` members from `BasePerson`.

Comment: @JeffRSon I am sorry for my English. Maybe I couldn't explain it good. I am not going to remove the indexer. I need it in the BasePerson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to *force* it, don't implement it on `BaseStudent`. Since `BaseStudent` is `abstract`, it does not *need* to implement all the `abstract` members from `BasePerson`.

```
public abstract class BasePerson
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
    public abstract object this[string propertyName]{get;set;}
}

public abstract class BaseStudent : BasePerson
{
    public string Test{get;set;}
}

public class Student : BaseStudent
{
    //must implement it here since Student isn't abstract!
}
```

`abstract` classes don't need to define *all* the `abstract` members of their inherited class, so you can feel free to pass up the responsibility to whatever concrete class would implement it. `Student` isn't defined to be `abstract` so it *must* implement whatever members have not already been implemented by the chain of base classes that it has inherited.

Comment: I didn't know I could do like this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was about to write the very same thing, +1